# How to properly place a <div> element in an <a> element

Tags: html

I know this is a common problem but I cannot solve it. In a table cell I have this code:

```
<a href="#1" class="nolink">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <p class="a4">
        <span class="big">1.</span>
        First thing to do
    </p>
</a>
```

According to the error:

> One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put
>   a block-level element (such as "`<p>`" or "`<table>`") inside an inline
>   element (such as "`<a>`", "`<span>`", or "`<font>`").

I understand the error and I know that I cannot place neither a `<div>` nor a `<p>` inside an `<a>`. I tried to set `display:block` on the `<a>` element, but that didn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Declare the DOCTYPE as HTML5

Comment: why not using javascript or some tricks for clickable the div????

Comment: Wow. That was new. Thanks. Add as a solution.

Comment: Do not put block elements inside inline elements. Apart from that, you haven't said what you're actually trying to do, so I don't know how this 'question' is answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: *Declare the DOCTYPE as HTML5*

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

A lot of things has been added, changed, tweaked and removed in HTML5 compared to HTML4. You can see a list of differences at w3c. The change you are after is among the changes introduced to the [Content-Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#content-model).

> The a element now has a transparent content model (except it does not allow interactive content descendants), meaning that it has the same content model as its parent. This means that the a element can now contain e.g. div elements, if its parent allows flow content.

Answer (score 1):

What is doing the validation? HTML5 no longer has this restriction, so the solution my be using the HTML5 doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

["Bloc-level Links" In HTML 5](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/)

Comment: Valid or not, this is bad practice IMO, the markup he presented serves no purpose there whatsoever. The `div` and `p` can easily be removed AND make cleaner code.

Comment: @jammykam If he gives the `a` a `display:block`, that is. Also "big" is not a very good class name, although better than "a1" or "a4".

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Agree on the class names, although a1 and a4 not much better either :-/

Comment: The div displays an image (I am using css sprites), that's why the div instead of an `<img>`.

Comment: Use a `span` instead of a `div`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `display:block` did not work? Are you trying to achieve something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8Np7/3/)? i.e. make the entire table cell clickable?

Here is the CSS:

```
td { width: 50%; }
.big { font-size: 1.5em; }
.nolink { display: block; background-color: yellow; }
.nolink:hover { background-color: #939393; }
.nolink .icon { 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 21px; 
    height: 21px;
    background-image: url('https://abs.twimg.com/a/1368740917/t1/img/twitter_web_sprite_icons.png');
    background-position: 0 -110px;

}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<table border=1 width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>column 1 text</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#1" class="nolink">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="big">1.</span>
                First thing to do
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[EDIT] Updated the code to add in a icon/image sprite inside the anchor link: 
[Working jSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E8Np7/3/)

Comment: Yes I want to make the table-cell clickable. I am sure the display:block does not work.

Comment: We need more code from you then if the above jsFiddle did not work. Add in the table and css you tried, maybe create it in jsFiddle too.

Comment: I updated the code to add in an icon in the anchor link with another span. See the jsFiddle I have linked to for a working demo.

Comment: I tried the `inline-block` earlier. Maybe I am going with HTML5 which ignores this error.

Comment: I would go with that option anyway regardless of whether you used this markup or not